# mb2portfolio increase skills limit

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, joomla-3.4, extensions, javascript

I am using a component called mb2portfolio with Joomla 3.4.8 and I'm having difficulties with the skills limit. It seems that the skills limit is set at 12, but I need 25 as the limit.

Please could someone help me find and increase the skills limit through php or a script?

I have contacted the original author of the plugin, but there has been no-reply for some time so I thought I would ask here as most of you guys are all on-point.

The extension can be found at http://mb2extensions.com/mb2-portfolio

Please note that I have menu items assigned to all projects and skills and I have 25 skills that need to be displayed.

All help much appreciated and if you need any more info please ask.

Thanks,
Richard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just downloaded `pkg_mb2portfolio-2.3.1.zip` from http://mb2extensions.com/downloads/mb2-portfolio, installed it on one of my test sites (because I'm also in search for decent Portfolio extension), and created 25 Skills (skill-01 to skill-25) with no problem. I've created five more, but it doesn't want to show any skill over 25th in `Mb2 Portfolio » Skills` menu type, even though they exist and can be assigned to projects.

It seems that developer heard your cries, and increased skills limit in v2.3.1 to 25 or even more ;-)

Comment: That's awesome, updated component and everything is working. Perhaps the developer saw this post, but thank you for taking the time to have a look at this for me. Much appreciated, Richard

Comment: Glad to be of little help... Take care...